# Adapt the size of a dhtmlx modal window to screen size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, window, dhtmlx

I have a web application that uses a dhtmlx modal window to show a form. That form is responsive, using Bootstrap, but the dhtmlx modal window does not adapt it's size to the window (is not responsive).

Right now, if I resize the window (browser) so it's smaller than the dhtmlx modal window, I will have a scrollbar. I would like the dhtmlx modal window to become smaller as the screen becomes smaller than the modal window.

[This is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidgourde/mpor3esh/) where you can see a dhtmlx modal window that contains a Bootstrap form. As you can see, it does not resize itself even if a part of it won't be seen by the user anymore.

```
dhxWins = new dhtmlXWindows();
dhxWins.attachViewportTo("vp");
w1 = dhxWins.createWindow("w1", 10, 10, 300, 250);
```

Is there a simple way to make a dhtmlx modal window take only the space it can have?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

dhtmlx modal window takes the sizes that you specify in the function `createWindow`.

You need to attach resize event to browser's window and call

```
dhxWins.window(id).setDimenstion(width, height)
```

to change dhtmlx modal window's size after browser resized.